# Datadog template variable

Tags: datadog, datadog-dashboard, terraform-provider-datadog

I have one question here: when defining [template variable via datadog](https://docs.datadoghq.com/dashboards/template_variables/), could we use regex for the default value? I am trying to exclude some value from the default value list. Thanks.